# How can I create my own exec function which has extended functionality?

Tags: scala, gatling

So I have many gatling rest call functions that look more or less like:

```
  val restCall = {
    exec(http("RestCall")
      .post("/restCall")
      .body(ElFileBody("json/body.json")).asJson
      .check(saveResponseToSession(status,bodyString,header))
    )
    .exec(session => {validateResponse(session)})
    .pause(Config.minDelayValue seconds, Config.maxDelayValue seconds)
  }
```

`.check(saveResponseToSession(status,bodyString,header))` <-- Is saving the body, status and header as session variables

`.exec(session => {validateResponse(session)})` <-- is validating the status, body and header according to my custom needs.

`.pause(Config.minDelayValue seconds, Config.maxDelayValue seconds)` <-- a simulation level pause that is used on all my transactions

These three functions are executed on all my API calls, what it means to me is hundreds of code duplication lines...

I am looking for a way to create/overide the .exec chain function and which will include these 3 functions at the end of each call.

So for example the above example will look like:

```
  val restCall = {
    customExec(http("RestCall")
      .post("/restCall")
      .body(ElFileBody("json/body.json")).asJson)
```

But will also include:

```
      .check(saveResponseToSession(status,bodyString,header))
    )
    .exec(session => {validateResponse(session)})
    .pause(Config.minDelayValue seconds, Config.maxDelayValue seconds)
  }
```

as I shown on the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a function that takes a ChainBuilder to run and then runs the validate and pause steps after.

```
val restCall = {
  exec(http("RestCall")
    .post("/restCall")
    .body(ElFileBody("json/body.json")).asJson
    .check(saveResponseToSession(status,bodyString,header))
  )
}

def validateAndWait(chain: ChainBuilder) = 
  exec(chain)
  .exec(session => {validateResponse(session)})
  .pause(Config.minDelayValue seconds, Config.maxDelayValue seconds)

def scn = scenario("action with validation").exec(validateAndWait(restCall))
```

Comment: out of interest, what are you doing in validateResponse? It will make your scripts less readable if you move validation away from the api call, so unless you're checking really generic things it might not be a good approach

Comment: Thanks for your interest! I am obviously new to Gatling and Scala so what I am doing with the validation might be... awkward. I wanted to print the Body, header sessionid and HTTP status in case of an error to be able to further debug the issue. So validate response do exactly that:

Comment: def validateResponse(session: Session): Validation[Session] = {
    val statusCode = session("HTTP_STATUS_CODE").as[String]
    val body = session("RESPONSE_BODY").as[String]
    val sessionId = session("RESPONSE_SESSION_ID").as[String]
    if (body.isEmpty() || body.contains("error\":") || statusCode != "200") {
      println(s"ERROR: session-id:[$sessionId], status-code:[$statusCode], body:[$body]")
    }
    return session
  }

Comment: By default, gatling will log failed requests and the contents of the session in the console - so you don't really need to manually get the response details to log

Comment: Most of our failed requests are sent back with HTTP 200 so gatling doesn't thing there is an issue.

Comment: you could add additional checks in to looks for the error text if you like. as I said, this has the advantage of keeping your checks in the same location as your requests.